# get recyclerview item index in the middle of the screen

Tags: android

i have a recyclerview with some item, i want to get index of item middle of screen. for now i only can get item index middle of first item visible and last item visible.

here's the screenshot:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zbVU.png)

and here's the code

```
myList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_penampilanobat_pilih_bentuk);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    itemWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_width);
    padding = (size.x - itemWidth) / 2;
    firstItemWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_item_width);

    allPixels = 0;
    ExtraItemsAdapter bentuk_adapter = new ExtraItemsAdapter(0, clone, padding);
    myList.setAdapter(bentuk_adapter);
    myList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int firstPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            int lastPos = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            int middle = (Math.abs(lastPos - firstPos) / 2 + firstPos) + 1;

            pos_icon_bentuk = middle;
                source = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(pengingat_obat_helper.getDrawable(pos_icon_shape));
            bentuk_obat.setBackground(FormatShapeColor.setColor(getActivity(), getColor(), source, pos_icon_warna_1));

        }
    });
```

i dont have any idea how to do this. anyone got idea? any answer will be appreciated. 
im sorry for my bad english,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need middle. Here is my solution.

```
int firstPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int lastPos  = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

int centerRecyclerView = activityMainBinding.recyclerView.getWidth() / 2;

int minDelta=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                
int middle = 0;
                
for(int i=firstPos;i<=lastPos;i++) {
    View view = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(i);
    if(view!=null) {
        int positionCenterView = view.getLeft() + (view.getRight() - view.getLeft()) / 2;
        int delta = Math.abs(centerRecyclerView - positionCenterView);
        if(delta<minDelta)
        {
            minDelta=delta;
            middle =i;
        }
    }
}
```